# Convert a PMML describe model in C/C++

Tags: c++, c, pmml

How to convert an already trained model (e.g. RFRegressor or a GBM) stored in PMML format in C/C++ code ?

Comment: Pick a language; C isn't C++.

Comment: Let's say C++, the idea is to be create a .so